# How can a space be added between 2 column values that make up a 3rd column in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have the following code to populate my ListBox on my WinForms app.

```
DataTable ListClass = GetDistinctRecords(LoadExceltoDatatable(plink), DistinctClass);
ListClass.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ClassCombo", typeof(string), "Class + ClassName"));
```

The values are being presented in the ListBox like this:  `0007Fishing Lures`
I'm trying to find out how to change the above code so it looks like this:

```
(0007) Fishing Lures
```

or like this

```
 0007 Fishing Lures
```

I'd prefer to add the () around the value, but I can settle for the space between the 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "'(' + Class + ') ' + ClassName"
```

or

```
 "Class + ' ' + ClassName"
```

cf documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression

Comment: All about the single quotes :( i was trying with double quotes and wasnt having luck googling the issue. Trying the suggestion now and will report back in a few minutes   thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your expression like this:

```
  ...new DataColumn("ClassCombo", typeof(string), "'(' + Class + ') ' + ClassName")
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, that was the problem, all my prior attempts were using double quotes instead of single..